# Android Java: Removing boundaries on the mouse

Tags: java, android, mouse

I have a special use case that requires a connected mouse to either wrap around the screen or to remove the boundaries on the mouse entirely.  Pretty much what I need is to be able to see the physical change in mouse movement.

The `MotionEvent` for the mouse pointer does not provide how the mouse actually moves, but only how it moves on the screen itself.  I have been using the `onHover(View, MotionEvent)` to get mouse data, and I can single out the mouse event by constraining the events to `InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE`, but it does not give any `InputDevice.SOURCE_MOUSE_RELATIVE` events, and I think that's the source I need to find out these relative mouse movements.

I am a beginner in Android development, so I don't know if I'm missing the obvious, but I've tried looking through the Android documentation. Is something like this even possible?